# Expiry Date Comparison and Marking Groups of Rows in a Table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to calculate expiry date differences on reward cards.

In the Track 2 Data sits the expiry, a 4 digit code written as YYMM (1907 for this month).

Transactions where two cards were used will show up in my report on multiple (together) lines. What I want to do is compare all the lines for each card and if there the reason the card was used twice is the expiry - then mark it to be ignored.

I'm not sure how to go about it, so I've come here!

```
;2130100020=1906192161277?3
;2130100020=2006192161076?:
;2130100020=2006192161076?:
;2130100020=2006192161076?:
```

Here are 4 examples. as shown above the expiry comes after the `=` sign.

The card number (hidden here for security) is is column B - this data is in column M and the notes section is column N.

The below is what I *think* I require of the code, but I can't even get my head around the logic, let alone the VBA

If the difference between the expiry is any of 99,100,199,200,299,300,299,400, then the card has expired/been reissued.

So in this case, Column N should read "ignore" on all 4 lines as above, but ignore the other ~2000 per day

---

So the question I am asking is:

What statements and code do I need to use to turn the pseudocode below into something VBA can understand?

---

```
+---------+-+-+-+---------+--------+
| Card No |e|t|c| Track 2 | Notes  | 
+---------+-+-+-+---------+--------+
| 1234567 | | | | =1906   | ignore |
| 1234567 | | | | =2006   | ignore |
| 1234567 | | | | =2006   | ignore |
| 1234567 | | | | =2006   | ignore |
| 9532211 | | | | =2201   | invest |
| 9532211 | | | | =2201   | invest |
| 9532211 | | | | =2201   | invest |
| 9532211 | | | | =2201   | invest |
```

[image]

Here you can see two card numbers. The green is set at ignore because one of the expiry's is matching the case: `2006-1906=100`. So every instance of this card in this range of cells can be set to **IGNORE**.

The next card in orange needs to be investigated because the expiry is the same across both, so that's not the reason it's on the report. Hence it needs investigating `2207-2207=0` - **INVESTIGATE**

Code:

```
Sub Reissue()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

    With ws.Range(Cells(lastRowBeforeImport, 13), Cells(lastRowAfterImport, 13))
    'In the above range
    'IF Expiry is different by 99, 100, 199, 200 etc to 499. 
    '    Example being diff between 2006 and 1906 is 100, so criteria is met
    'Change NOTES column to REISSUE - IGNORE
    End With


End Sub
```

---

EDIT:
With Xabier's answer, I get the following

[image]

This is correct as it shows the line with a different expiry that matches the case (here the difference is 300) and the line says "ignore". Only change would be to have the whole block say ignore as every case can now be ignored.

Comment: You should ask a question, it is very unlcear what you expect us to answer.

Comment: The problem to understand what you want is probably that none of your example data meets the criteria `IF Expiry is *99 or *00 THEN` so ther is nothing to change to `ignore`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, something like the below would achieve your desired results:

```
Sub Reissue()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

For i = lastRowBeforeImport To lastRowAfterImport
If ws.Cells(i, 13).Value - ws.Cells(i - 1, 13).Value = 99 Or ws.Cells(i, 13).Value - ws.Cells(i - 1, 13).Value = 0 Then
    ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Ignore"
Else
    ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Investigate"
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Further to the comment, I've used a Case Statement to see if the value matches any of the mentioned:

```
Sub Reissue()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

For i = lastRowBeforeImport To lastRowAfterImport
    Select Case ws.Cells(i, 13).Value - ws.Cells(i - 1, 13).Value
          Case 0, 99, 100, 199, 200, 299, 300, 399, 400
              ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Ignore"
          Case Else
              ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = "Investigate"
    End Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I believe that's what I'm looking for. My criteria was not clear though, it's where the difference between the expiry is any of :99, 100, 199, 200, 299, 300, 399, 400. I have edited OP

Comment: @Badja I've now updated my answer to reflect your comments, please could you accept my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the change in answer. It's not quite answered my question, as it doesn't change the whole block, only one line - but I think I can cope with that. Edited my answer to show

Comment: @Badja, I forgot to add 0 to the Case Statement, I believe this now should work as you expect it to....

Comment: Brilliant! I'm still seeing an issue where if a card number is clearly different, it's telling me to investigate, as it's not checking for that. Different cards have different expiry's, so that's expected. I was hoping to look at each record of a card number as a "block" then move on to the next - do I need to change my question to reflect this?